# How do you set cache headers in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

In an annotation-based Spring MVC controller, what is the preferred way to set cache headers for a specific path?

Comment: For new users, [this is probably the answer you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172925/476716)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.html), which is the base class for all Spring controllers has quite a few methods dealing with cache headers:

```
/* Set whether to use the HTTP 1.1 cache-control header. Default is "true".
 * <p>Note: Cache headers will only get applied if caching is enabled
 * (or explicitly prevented) for the current request. */
public final void setUseCacheControlHeader();

/* Return whether the HTTP 1.1 cache-control header is used. */
public final boolean isUseCacheControlHeader();

/* Set whether to use the HTTP 1.1 cache-control header value "no-store"
 * when preventing caching. Default is "true". */
public final void setUseCacheControlNoStore(boolean useCacheControlNoStore);

/* Cache content for the given number of seconds. Default is -1,
 * indicating no generation of cache-related headers.
 * Only if this is set to 0 (no cache) or a positive value (cache for
 * this many seconds) will this class generate cache headers.
 * The headers can be overwritten by subclasses, before content is generated. */
public final void setCacheSeconds(int seconds);
```

They can either be invoked within your controller prior to content generation or specified as bean properties in Spring context.

Comment: But, as I wrote in my question, I use an annotation-based controller that doesn't subclass from any spring base class. How will this help me?

Comment: If you want to alter cache settings depending on **specific path**, extending `AbstractController` is by far the easiest solution. If you want to apply your cache settings to all controllers, you can specify them on `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` instance in Spring context for annotation-based controllers. Here's an example: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder (disregard the init binder, you don't need it)

Comment: Because my question concerned how to do this with an annotations-based controller. Your solution only applies to controllers that subclass WebContentGenerator. Isn't it so?

Comment: I've adressed that in my above comment. If you think you'll find a better solution I wish you luck.

Comment: that's why I up-voted your comment. Why didn't you edit your answer instead?

Comment: To clarify, AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter does extend WebContentGenerator which gives you all the cache header options. Remember, you need to set <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" /> or a positive value for any of the cache headers to show up.

Answer (score 67):

I just encountered the same problem, and found a good solution already provided by the framework.  The `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor` class allows you to define default caching behaviour, plus path-specific overrides (with the same path-matcher behaviour used elsewhere).  The steps for me were:

1. Ensure my instance of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` does not have the "cacheSeconds" property set.
2. Add an instance of `WebContentInterceptor`:

   ```
   <mvc:interceptors>
   ...
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor" p:cacheSeconds="0" p:alwaysUseFullPath="true" >
       <property name="cacheMappings">
           <props>
               <!-- cache for one month -->
               <prop key="/cache/me/**">2592000</prop>
               <!-- don't set cache headers -->
               <prop key="/cache/agnostic/**">-1</prop>
           </props>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ...
   </mvc:interceptors>
   ```

After these changes, responses under /foo included headers to discourage caching, responses under /cache/me included headers to encourage caching, and responses under /cache/agnostic included no cache-related headers.

---

If using a pure Java configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  /* Time, in seconds, to have the browser cache static resources (one week). */
  private static final int BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL = 604800;

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
     .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
     .addResourceLocations("/images/")
     .setCachePeriod(BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
  }
}
```

See also: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html

Comment: I tried to use this for images stored in the DB. I can easily retrieve them. They show up, but FireBug always keeps telling me status "200 Ok", so no caching. Any ideas?

Comment: This won't work because I don't have a prefix of mvc, or p. What are they supposed to be?

Comment: Jesse - check the root element of your context def file; you should have a namespace element like 'xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"', and another attribute named 'xsi:schemaLocation' with a value that includes 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd'.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-FormattingConversionService for an example of a typical XML config.

Comment: Can you tell which xml namespace p: refers to ?

Comment: You should only need to add `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` as long as you're using the 3.1 xsd.

Comment: This setup is not working for me. I did not do the <p...> thing I explicity mentioned a <property name="cacheSeconds">2345</property>

Answer (score 33):

The answer is quite simple:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/find/employer/{employerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List getEmployees(@PathVariable("employerId") Long employerId, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return employeeService.findEmployeesForEmployer(employerId);
    }

}
```

Code above shows exactly what you want to achive. You have to do two things. Add "final HttpServletResponse response" as your parameter. And then set header Cache-Control to no-cache.

Comment: this would have to be added to every request. not a good solution for adding the header to all requests across the board.

Comment: @JesseJ What part didn't work?  I tried and it works for me.

Comment: @yincrash, quoting OP: _what is the preferred way to set cache headers for a **specific path**_

Answer (score 19):

Starting with [Spring 4.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.2.html#_web_improvements_2) you can do this:

```
import org.springframework.http.CacheControl;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController
public class CachingController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/cachedapi")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDto> getPermissions() {

        MyDto body = new MyDto();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .body(body);
    }
}
```

`CacheControl` object is a builder with many configuration options, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/CacheControl.html)

Answer (score 11):

You could use a Handler Interceptor and use the postHandle method provided by it:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

```
postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
```

then just add a header as follows in the method:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Answer (score 5):

I found `WebContentInterceptor` to be the easiest way to go.

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
{
    WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
    interceptor.addCacheMapping(CacheControl.noCache(), "/users", "admin");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can define a anotation for this: `@CacheControl(isPublic = true, maxAge = 300, sMaxAge = 300)`, then render this anotation to HTTP Header with Spring MVC interceptor. or do it dynamic:

```
int age = calculateLeftTiming();
String cacheControlValue = CacheControlHeader.newBuilder()
      .setCacheType(CacheType.PUBLIC)
      .setMaxAge(age)
      .setsMaxAge(age).build().stringValue();
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cacheControlValue)) {
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", cacheControlValue);
}
```

Implication can be found here: [优雅的Builder模式](http://arganzheng.life/builder-pattern-in-action.html)

BTW: I just found that Spring MVC has build-in support for cache control:
Google WebContentInterceptor or CacheControlHandlerInterceptor or CacheControl, you will find it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old one, but those who are googling, this might help:

```
@Override
protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.put("/", "2592000");
    mappings.put("/admin", "-1");
    interceptor.setCacheMappings(mappings);

    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you can set response headers directly.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extend AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter to look for a custom cache control annotation and set the http headers accordingly.